# Will I lose privileges when we advance to Public Beta?

Tags: support, beta, reputation, privileges

It's pretty clear that we will advance to Public Beta now and probably in 3 days. If/When we do, will I lose access to privileges that I already have. For example, will I lose my ability to see vote counts (currently at 100, at 750 in Public Beta)?

Comment: Who said we will go public in probably 3 days? If you look at the private beta wall on the site while logged out you will see ~5 weeks.

Comment: Up to 5 weeks @HenryWHHackv3.0

Comment: Where did you get the number for 3 days from?

Comment: After 7 days we can graduate to public beta. weve been in beta for 4 days. 7-4=3. So... Subtraction @Mast

Comment: Anyway, the full answer is already available as FAQ on MSE. Do you want a copy of it?

Comment: Yes, please @Mast

Comment: I don't think the 7 days are guaranteed, it's more of a minimum that it takes *at least* that long to get out of private beta, but how beta work have changes a bit over the years. I don't have a source with that unfortunately.

Comment: The 7 days not being an exact number is already explained [here](https://languagedesign.meta.stackexchange.com/a/111/10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: If you don't meet the new threshold, yes, you will lose privileges.

This question gets asked every private beta, so it has FAQ status on main meta (MSE): [What are the reputation requirements for privileges on sites, and how do they differ per site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/269301). A partial copy:

---

The **three main types** are covered in the table below. Some minor changes to individual sites are indicated with a † in the table and explained further below.

| Privilege | "Private beta" | "Beta" | "Full" |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Create posts](/help/privileges/create-posts) | 1 | 1 | 1 |  |
| [Participate in meta](/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) | 5 | 5 | 5 | † |
| Skip lecture on how to ask | - | - | 10 | † |
| [Create community-wiki answers](/help/privileges/community-wiki) | 10 | 10 | 10 |  |
| [Remove new-user restrictions](/help/privileges/new-user)¹ | 1 | 10 | 10 | † |
| [Vote up](/help/privileges/vote-up) | 1 | 15 | 15 |  |
| [Flag posts](/help/privileges/flag-posts) | 15 | 15 | 15 |  |
| Post instantly self-answered questions² | 15 | 15 | 15 |  |
| [Comment everywhere](/help/privileges/comment) | 1 | 50 | 50 | † |
| [Set bounties](/help/privileges/set-bounties) | 75 | 75 | 75 |  |
| [Edit community wikis](/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki) | 1 | 100 | 100 |  |
| [Vote down](/help/privileges/vote-down) | 1 | 125 | 125 | † |
| [Create tags](/help/privileges/create-tags) | 1 | 150 | 300 | † |
| Vote in moderator elections | - | 150 | 150 | ♦ |
| Association bonus³ | 200 | 200 | 200 | ♦ |
| Shown in network reputation graph and flair | 200 | 200 | 200 |  |
| Shown as "beta user" on Area 51 | 200 | 200 | - |  |
| [Reduced advertisements](/help/privileges/reduced-ads) | - | - | 200 |  |
| Reputation leagues, top x% link in profile | 201 | 201 | 201 | ♦ |
| Qualify for first Yearling badge | 201 | 201 | 201 | ♦ |
| [View close votes](/help/privileges/view-close-votes)⁴ | 1 | 250 | 250 |  |
| Run for moderator | - | 300 | 300 | † |
| [Access review queues](/help/privileges/access-review-queues)⁵ | 350 | 350 | 500 | † |
| [See vote counts](/help/privileges/established-user) | 100 | 750 | 1000 | † |
| [Edit freely, SE and LQP/A queue](/help/privileges/edit)⁶ | 500 | 1000 | 2000 |  |
| No popup asking to comment when downvoting | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 | ♦ |
| Non-nofollow link in user profile⁷ | 2000 | 2000 | 2000 |  |
| [Suggest tag synonyms](/help/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms) | 1250 | 1250 | 2500 |  |
| [Vote to close and reopen](/help/privileges/close-questions) | 15 | 500 | 3000 |  |
| [Review tag wiki edits](/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) | 750 | 1500 | 5000 |  |
| [Moderator tools](/help/privileges/moderator-tools)⁸ | 1000 | 2000 | 10000 |  |
| Reduce captchas | 1000? | 2000 | 10000 |  |
| [Protect questions](/help/privileges/protect-questions) | 1750 | 3500 | 15000 |  |
| [Trusted user](/help/privileges/trusted-user)⁹ | 2000 | 4000 | 20000 |  |
| [Access to site analytics](/help/privileges/site-analytics) | 2500 | 5000 | 25000 |  |

<sup>† Some site-specific change applies (see "Site-specific changes" below)

- The privilege does not apply at this stage

♦ Privilege is purely reputation-based; being a ♦ moderator does not suffice

¹ post more than eight hyperlinks (50 on Skeptics); less rate limiting; post images†

² compose and post a self-answer to your question at the same time as your question; if you don't have this privilege, you can still self-answer after posting your question

³ +100 reputation on any associated account once you reached this on any site

⁴ see and cast close and reopen votes on own questions

⁵ access the *First questions*, *First answers*, *Late answers*, and *Triage* (SO and Physics only) review queues

⁶ edit posts of others without review; access the *Suggested edits* and the *Low quality posts* or *Low quality answers* review queues

⁷ the website link in your profile has a [rel=nofollow attribute](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/327588) if you have less than 2000 reputation, to make it not count for SEO purposes

⁸ see deleted posts, reviews of others; moderator tools (various information); vote to delete questions two days after closure

⁹ edit tag wikis without review; vote to delete negatively scoring answers; vote to delete closed questions with −3 or lower score without delay</sup>

---

The moment you go from Private beta to Beta, the new privilege requirements will be in effect. If you did meet the privilege levels before but not anymore, you will lose the privilege. The same happens when you lose sufficient reputation using downvotes, (on non-CW answers) bounties (giving the reputation to someone else) or getting spam flagged. More on that in another MSE FAQ, [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/269301)